# CSS mobile media styles with manual toggling

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, media

So I'm trying to build a mobile and desktop version of a website simultaneously (using a MediaWiki engine, if anybody is interested). Since I don't have much experience with mobile device building, I was looking around for some good mobile development practices. In the end, I feel media queries are good for what I need to do, mostly because double-publishing on separate domains (like m.foo.com vs foo.com) is not possible for this task.

The shortcoming to CSS media queries, it seems, is the apparent inability for phone users to view the site in desktop format whenever they want to (Google or YouTube is a good example of this when accessed using a phone).

Is there any way for me to freely toggle between desktop and mobile stylesheets developed with media queries? Would using javascript be too bulky for a mobile device to download?

I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

EDIT: For clarification, yes, I want to click a link or button on the mobile style to switch to a desktop style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 90% sure that it is **not possible with CSS alone** but can easily be accomplished with **PHP or Javascript**. It shouldn't be too bulky to use javascript.

Some examples

[PHP Style Switcher](http://robballou.com/switcher/v1/index.php).

[Javascript Style Switcher](http://www.inetsolution.com/turnleft/post/CSS-Style-Switcher-A-quick-and-dirty-how-to.aspx)

[Jquery Style Switcher](http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/stylesheet-switcher/)

Comment: It's also possible with PHP via the method GET and a simple `if () {} else {}`

Comment: PHP doesn't seem to be an option for me, sadly. In my situation I don't have access to the server hosting our site.  

I felt that Javascript would be needed... but if it's not too much to ask, what would this code look like? I'm not too familiar with Javascript and what it can do.